# Android java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1

Tags: java, android

I've just received this crash log by a user and I can't understand what caused it. My app is a text editor. I have a TextWatcher on the TextView but I'm not sure if that is the problem, since the logcat dosen't contain any line of my app.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7231)
at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7290)
at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:8880)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:962)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:496)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:672)
at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:435)
at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:333)
at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: put your code where you are getting exception.

Comment: As i said in the question, i recived this crash log from the play console so i can't know where is the problem :S

Comment: double click on `logcat` and check where is exception.

Comment: If you only have **1** element, you can only index **0**, since the array range is **0, ..., (n - 1)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this can help someone else, but to fix this bug I've done this:

I have an EditText, with a TextWatcher.

The error is raised by this setText call:

```
editText.setText("");
```

To solve this I had to:

1. remove the listener,
2. set the text to the empty string,
3. finally, re-add the listener.

Comment: Please, mark it as the best answer if it's the solution to your problem.

Comment: @PiotrChojnacki i'll do it asap, so tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

seems this happens if you edit the attached state of a text watcher in the text watcher itself.  e.g., i see this happen if i remove the textwatcher in a watcher method itself.

to verify, move the contents of onTextChanged to afterTextChanged, and see if the new stacktrace is triggered from TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged instead.

to work around it, move that work to a handler posted from the method, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

So late, but for anyone can be useful:

Check if your `EditText` has the `textAllCaps="true"` attribute and remove it if needed.